# Allowing Profile's Access to their Respected Links

Tags: apex, javascript, profile, access

I am currently working on a piece of code that will allow a certain group of profiles launch out from Salesforce to another web application. Any other profiles will be staying on Salesforce. I have created a "Custom Setting" for the launch out. Right now my code will only open a new tab on Salesforce and provide the details page for all users (Which is okay). I need the code to, when the user clicks on the number, keep users who have the custom setting on Salesforce, and any other profiles who don't have the custom setting need to be launched out.

Here is my current code~

Apex Code for Profile Access/Custom Setting:

```
@AuraEnabled
public static Boolean hasDVLAccess(){
    Boolean returnValue;
    returnValue = (Boolean) getCustomerSummaryViewAccessDetails().get('DVL_Launch_Access__c');
    return returnValue;
```

Controller Apex:

```
/**
 * @description method returns access to view DVL details page
 * @return boolean access value
 */
@AuraEnabled
public static Boolean getDvlAccess() {
    return AT_ProfileAccess.hasDVLAccess();
}
```

Component Helper:

```
launchDVL: function(component, row, action) {
        console.log(row);
        var launchDVLDetails = $A.get("e.force:navigateToSObject");
        launchDVLDetails.setParams({
            "recordId": row['RecordId'],
            "slideDevName": "related"
        });
        launchDVLDetails.fire();
  },
...
getDvlAccess: function(component){
        var action = component.get("c.getDvlAccess");
        action.setCallback(this, function(a){
           component.set("v.hasDvlAccess", a.getReturnValue());
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
     },
...
chooseDetailLink: function(component, row, action, helper, agreementIndexId, policyNumber, lineOfBusiness, agentAssocId, nechoAppName, status, actionName, productDescription, policyActionUrl){

            if('v.hasDVLAccess' != true) {
                helper.launchDVL(component, row, action, helper);//params

            } else {
                helper.launchWebNecho(component, agreementIndexId, policyNumber, lineOfBusiness, agentAssocId, nechoAppName, status, actionName, productDescription, policyActionUrl);//params
            }
        }
```

Competent Controller:

```
//Part of a much larger switch statement
case 'launch_policy':  


 helper.chooseDetailLink(component, row, action, helper, row['AgreementIndexId'], row['PolicyNumber'], lob, row['AgentAssociateId'], 'policy', row['Status'], action.name, row['ProductDescription'], row['PolicyActionUrl']);
```

Comment: I am not quite sure exactly what the problem is. You've explain to us what you want to do... but I don't know what is wrong...

Comment: Haha I understand what you mean, but that's really not helpful.

Comment: Gevin, my recommendation is to check the [Ask] document to get better answers. It almost looked like you were asking for somebody to write code for you, which is not exactly what this forum is for. If that is the case, my recommendation is to do some research, try a few things, and then come back and ask specific questions about why your chosen solution might not be working. Good luck!

Comment: Imagine a number on a data table. That number is connected to a link which brings users to a detail page. There is two ways to view these details. One way is on Salesforce, the other is a separate application NOT on Salesforce. So, only one group of users is allowed view the details on Salesforce. All other groups have to view details on an application separate from Salesforce. Right now when any profile selects the number on the table they just stay on the Salesforce. I need the profiles who I have not created the Custom Setting for to be launched out of Salesforce to the application.

Comment: Thank You for the advice! I'll do what I can.

Comment: You want to research "Custom Permissions", by the way. I think that is going to be the basis for what you want to achieve

Comment: I wish I could use Custom Permission in this case, but I can't. Thanks for the advice again, this issue is a little more complex than that I think haha but thanks for helping!